# How to read/import a CSV once and create code so that you don't have to read/import again

Tags: r, csv

I have an R script that I would like to share with people, but it currently depends on reading many separate csv files into data frames in order to run. I’m wondering if there’s any quick and easy way to read the csv files and then create the lines of code to create the data frame without having to read external files in the future (I have dozens of csv files with hundreds of records each, but I only want to share the .R file).

As an example, I currently have:

```
> species <- read.csv("species.csv")
> species
  SpeciesID        ScientificName Mortality
1        11      Acer_platanoides      2.27
2        57 Gleditsia_triacanthos      1.33
3       132         Tilia_cordata      1.33
4         1        Abies_balsamea      3.33
```

After reading the csv databases once, I would like to create the code so that I don’t have to read the csv again (and so that I can send people one R script and not an R script with dozens of other files).

So, can the above somehow lead to the following, without having to write it all out manually?? Thank you.

```
> species <- data.frame("SpeciesID" = c(11, 57, 132, 1),
+                       "ScientificName" = c("Acer_platanoides", "Gleditsia_triacanthos", "Tilia_cordata", "Abies_balsamea"),
+                       "Mortality" = c(2.27, 1.33, 1.33, 3.34))
> species
  SpeciesID        ScientificName Mortality
1        11      Acer_platanoides      2.27
2        57 Gleditsia_triacanthos      1.33
3       132         Tilia_cordata      1.33
4         1        Abies_balsamea      3.34
```

Comment: You could use `dput(species)`. The output will be code that recreates the variable species. But if you have "hundreds of files" it may be a very big chunk of code.

Comment: Thanks G5W. It's a big chunk, but I ran the following code (with a bit of cleaning) and it wasn't too bad: 
`file_list <- list.files(pattern = glob2rx('*.csv'))

for(i in 1:length(file_list)){
  temp <- read.csv(file_list[i])
  dput(temp)
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you need to do to [create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Following Joris Meys' solution `dput()` makes it pretty easy.

An example from the linked solution:

```r
> dput(head(iris,4))
structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 
3, 3.2, 3.1), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("setosa", 
"versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Sepal.Length", 
"Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species"), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```